# OCR text Reader for iOS

Tags: ios, ocr, tesseract

I need to read text from image that taken from camera. For example i have one cheque and i take image of cheque and render image according to size that i need to cut after rendering image the image i get i want to read text on that. Like i render cheque book and cut only account number or amount on check and store in NSString. I am using OCR Class

```
Tesseract *tessec=[[Tesseract alloc]initWithDataPath:@"tessdata" language:@"eng"];
[tessec setVariableValue:@"0123456789" forKey:@"tessedit_char_whitelist"];
[tessec setImage:_selectedImage];
[tessec recognize];
NSString *testStr=(NSString*)[tessec recognizedText];
NSLog(@"Image data convertion is %@",testStr);
```

But its not giving proper text on check.

Answer (score 1):

You can preprocess the image before using the tesseract engine.
You can use the pre-processing methods like noise removal, background removal,threshold adjustments etc..

Please go through [this](http://misteroleg.wordpress.com/2012/12/19/ocr-using-tesseract-and-imagemagick-as-pre-processing-task/).
It may help you.

Answer (score 0):

You can train tesseract with fonts in cheques and use that. [Here's the link](https://code.google.com/p/tesseract-ocr/wiki/TrainingTesseract3)

Comment: I did but i am not able to get proper text from Check, Some time i get proper text but some time some additional character coming. Could you please share any working POC if you have

Comment: for that i need to know the characters. Can you upload cheque image?

Comment: Actually I need not want to read all text from image.Step-1 i take image of check,Step-2 i render image and cut image with box like width-200px and height-30px in this box i cut only account number that is on check then i pass this render image to  
    [tessec setImage:_selectedImage];
    [tessec recognize];
    NSString *testStr=(NSString*)[tessec recognizedText];
   Its coming account number coming but some time its add additional character or its skip some character

Comment: Sorry i am not able to upload my check image.I did not find any option to upload image.

Comment: Hello Please share me if you have any solutions of my question.